# NVM: Getting Permission denied with nvm install command

Tags: node.js, linux, nvm

I recently fresh-installed Ubuntu 21.04 and wanted to install nvm:

`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash`

Then closed and re-opened the terminal. When requesting an install of version `12.16.3` (have tried with other versions as well). I'm getting the following error:

```
nvm install 12.16.3
Downloading and installing node v12.16.3...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.16.3/node-v12.16.3-linux-x64.tar.xz...
Warning: Failed to create the file 
Warning: /home/sauronnikko/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v12.16.3-linux-x64/node-v12.16.
Warning: 3-linux-x64.tar.xz: Permission denied
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination

Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.16.3/node-v12.16.3-linux-x64.tar.xz failed, trying source.
grep: /home/sauronnikko/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v12.16.3-linux-x64/node-v12.16.3-linux-x64.tar.xz: No such file or directory
Provided file to checksum does not exist.
Binary download failed, trying source.
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.16.3/node-v12.16.3.tar.xz...
Warning: Failed to create the file 
Warning: /home/sauronnikko/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v12.16.3/node-v12.16.3.tar.xz: 
Warning: Permission denied
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination

Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.16.3/node-v12.16.3.tar.xz failed, trying source.
grep: /home/sauronnikko/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v12.16.3/node-v12.16.3.tar.xz: No such file or directory
Provided file to checksum does not exist.
```

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Posted an [issue](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/2507) to nvm's repo

Turns out the problem was with `curl` and that I had installed it with `snap` instead of regular `apt install curl`.

Comment: this solved my problem as well as i have mentioned in a separate answer

Comment: i hate computers so much

Answer (score 105):

uninstall `curl` installed with `snap`

```
sudo snap remove curl
```

install `curl` from `apt`

```
sudo apt install curl
```

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue (having previously installed *curl* with *snap*). After UNinstalling curl *nvm* worked as expected.

```
$ sudo snap remove curl
```

Comment: JFYI.. Dont forget to restart terminal after removing curl

Comment: In my case I just uninstalled curl from snap and installed through apt, in sequence, without restarting terminal I could repeat `nvm install --lts` and it worked as a charm.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue. It was due to the lack of "libssl-dev". Run the following command before you start the installation process for nvm

`sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev curl git-core`

Comment: Reinstalling the `curl` fixed my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

**This worked**

In simple words i did this and it worked...

```
>snap list
>sudo snap remove curl
```

This will delete curl that was installed through snap.
We need to install using apt

```
>sudo apt-get install curl
```

Now we need to install nvm using curl

```
>curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash
```

Now simply install the node version u want.

```
>nvm install v14.17.0
```

In order to list all nvm version simply do so.

```
>nvm ls
```

And in order to switch just type the following command.

```
>nvm use v12.X.XX
```

Answer (score 2):

It says `Permission denied`, try the same command with `sudo`

`sudo curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash`

Answer (score 2):

I have had the exact same issue today as well, I'm not sure if its been an issue with NVM or if its just my Linux install being screwy but I have managed to get around it for the moment by manually downloading the tar file for the node version you want to install, move it to nvm's cache and then running nvm install again. I'll leave exact steps below and I'll try and remember to come back and update this Q if I work out why curl doesnt want to create a file in the .nvm dir

I have tried everything I can think of to try allow curl to save to the nvm directory, installing nvm using sudo, chown the dir, add full rwx permissions for user group and other for the dir, manually install nvm, nothing had worked for me so at present my best solution is below :)

Work around fix (using v16.1.0 of node as the example):

1 - run the curl command to download the version of node you want into your home directory

```
curl https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.1.0/node-v16.1.0-linux-x64.tar.xz --output node-v16.1.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
```

2 - copy the file to the nvm cache

```
sudo mv node-v16.1.0-linux-x64.tar.xz ~/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v16.1.0-linux-x64/node-v16.1.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
```

3 - run nvm install again

```
nvm install node (or whatever version you are trying to install)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try creating folder and giving write permission to it:

1. Create folder
   `mkdir ~/.nvm`
2. Give permission for example:
   `sudo chmod 777 ~/.nvm`

Note :In my case, I passed these steps, but I got another permission error during installation of a node version with nvm, and solved it by using this command:
`sudo chmod 777 /private/tmp`

Comment: I already had the folder, but for some reason write permissions were denied. Running sudo chmod 777 ~/.nvm fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

check your NVM_DIR environment variable, mine was set incorrectly after transferred from an older machine

Answer (score 0):

I am on a Windows machine (Windows 10) and I use Git Bash (I realize this is not supported -- see below).

I got a Permissions denied error on trying to [`nvm install --lts`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71902980/how-to-determine-latest-stable-version-of-node-from-nvm#comment136719010_75268277)

The Permissions denied was related to this folder:

```
C:\Users\{my_user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3
```

I don't know what was wrong with that file/folder; `python3.exe` and etc were all 0 bytes. So I deleted the WindowsApps , and I got past this `Permission denied` error

**BE CAREFUL**, not sure this is appropriate for you, I only did it on the assumption that `\AppData\Local` is cached data -- which can be deleted without problems

---

After getting past the Permissions denied error, but I got a new error like `Did not find a new enough assembler`

I was able to fix this assembler related error by running the command: `cd "$NVM_DIR" && git checkout master` as described [here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/2534#issuecomment-894755907)

Answer (score -1):

For me the problem was different, and the solution was to create an SSH Key for GitHub and add it in my profile.

See related documentation [here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)