# nvm install --lts keeps failing no matter what I try.. I already have v12 working properly as default under nvm

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, nvm

[image: Screenshot]

On a Ubuntu 20.04 server - I've also tried removing and reinstalling curl as per [This SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67541374/nvm-getting-permission-denied-with-nvm-install-command/67590451#67590451)

[This](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/2492)

is also open.. So no idea how to install Node v14 LTS under nvm now..

Comment: Is this happening inside a VirtualBox VM by any chance?

Comment: Where are you from? Maybe your Internet connection has been censored.

Comment: @pan93412 Nope. Internet connection is absolutely fine.

Comment: @szx Yes. But everything else is working A-Ok. Even node v12 downloaded and installed properly before.

Comment: @Storm there is a bug in VirtualBox 6 that leads to corruption of downloaded files, try updating to the latest version and disabling Hyper-V, or just use VirtualBox 5.

Comment: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/19695?cversion=0&cnum_hist=6

Comment: is this a reinstall? If so, does NVM have an option similar to --reinstall?

Answer (score 0):

The [readme](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md#troubleshooting-on-linux) on the github for NVM says to use the provided install script for Linux installs. This can be achieved with curl or wget:

`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash`

`wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash`

I recommend that you click the link and read, as their is quite a bit of related info there.

Answer (score 0):

I was interested and just tested it out in a clean docker container (ubuntu:20.04) (as I dont use node that often), and it looked pretty straight forward:

```
apt-get update -y 
apt-get install -y curl
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash
source ~/.bashrc
nvm version
# none
nvm install --lts --default
nvm version
# v14.17.0
```

If it not that, then I would also assume, that the issue is related to your general environment, like network inspection, proxy access or else.

Answer (score 0):

As it is visible from the logs, **the checksum process keeps failing in a repeated manner**. And there have been issues highlighting that [some ISO images can show issue with hashing process due to Windows 10 components.](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=97903&p=474815#p474815) , which implicitly effects the checksum process under a guest environment on VirtualBox.

You can complete the steps provided [by VirtualBox team](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=97919) there to resolve this issue, as pointed out on [Virtual Box's forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=97919):

> it's Hyper-V that is causing the checksum problem you posted about, not the version of Virtualbox.