# Nvm install - Warning: Failed to open the file - Permission Denied

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, installation, nvm

I currently have node installed on my computer (ubuntu) with the `v12.22.9` version and I'm trying to install the `v10.22.0` version with the following command: `nvm install v10.22.0` but I always get the error described below. How do I resolve it?

```
Downloading and installing node v10.22.0...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.22.0/node-v10.22.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
Warning: Failed to open the file                                               
Warning: /home/wand/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v10.22.0-linux-x64/node-v10.22.0-linux
Warning: -x64.tar.xz: Permission denied
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination

Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.22.0/node-v10.22.0-linux-x64.tar.xz failed, trying source.
grep: /home/wand/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v10.22.0-linux-x64/node-v10.22.0-linux-x64.tar.xz: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente
Provided file to checksum does not exist.
Binary download failed, trying source.
Detected that you have 12 CPU core(s)
Running with 11 threads to speed up the build
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.22.0/node-v10.22.0.tar.xz...
Warning: Failed to open the file                                               
Warning: /home/wand/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v10.22.0/node-v10.22.0.tar.xz: 
Warning: Permission denied
                                                                            0.0%curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination

Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.22.0/node-v10.22.0.tar.xz failed, trying source.
grep: /home/wand/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v10.22.0/node-v10.22.0.tar.xz: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente
Provided file to checksum does not exist.
```

I tried to install a previous version of node but it gave an error.

Comment: The problem was solved below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67541374/nvm-getting-permission-denied-with-nvm-install-command